# Get specific Item of NSToolbar

Tags: swift, macos, nstoolbar

I want to have a NSToolbar in my macOS-App. I have created a Toolbar in the Window of my storyboard and connected this with a swift class called MainToolbar.
The source text of this class is the following (at this moment):

```
import Cocoa

class MainToolbar: NSToolbar, NSToolbarDelegate {

    override init(identifier: String) {
        super.init(identifier: identifier)
    }

}
```

[image]

Now, I want to change the title of the Colors-Element and add a share button as two examples.
The Colors-Element has the identifier "NSToolbarShowColorsItem" in the storyboard.

I know, that there is the possibility of getting the items with "self.items", but there is now way of adding elements because it is immutable. And I also cannot find the way of getting elements with the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you have to go to the storyboard and click on the toolbar.

The toolbar will open up and show two sections. The top section is the available buttons and the bottom section is the default buttons for the application.

I don't think it is wise to actually change the standard buttons, i.e. change the meaning of Colors. It is better to add a new NSToolbarItem to the top section. After you added it, you can double click on the title to give it a title and you can set the image by providing an image name in the Attribute Inspector.

Next you drag the new button from the top section to the bottom section.

Actions should be set from the top section and not from the bottom section.